# How to delete a line with variable search using sed command

Tags: shell-script, sed

What is wrong with the `sed` command on deleting the line which matches the input data?

InputData.txt

```
123,
1234,
1453,
```

Datatodelete.txt

```
1234,hellofirstline
123,hellosecondline
14676,hellothirdline
1453,hellofourthline
```

expected output in the Datatodelete.txt

```
14676,hellothirdline
```

Script:

```
echo "the script starts now"
while read EachLine
do
  echo $EachLine
  sed "/$EachLine/d" < /home/Datatodelete.txt >/home/dummy
done < /home/InputData.txt
```

Answer (score 5):

Your `sed` command doesn't work because during the loop, each time it reads a line, it deletes that line (and only that line) from the full input file, outputting it to `/home/dummy`. This means that the output file gets overwritten each time. So the first iteration of the loop removes the line starting with **123,** but then the second iteration uses the original full file which still includes this line.

Try `grep` instead:

```
grep -vFf /home/InputData.txt /home/Datatodelete.txt > /home/dummy
```

From `man grep`:

```
   -F, --fixed-strings
          Interpret PATTERN as a  list  of  fixed  strings,  separated  by
          newlines,  any  of  which is to be matched.  (-F is specified by
          POSIX.)

   -f FILE, --file=FILE
          Obtain  patterns  from  FILE,  one  per  line.   The  empty file
          contains zero patterns, and therefore matches nothing.   (-f  is
          specified by POSIX.)
   -v, --invert-match
          Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.  (-v
          is specified by POSIX.)
```

Comment: Depending on what else is in `Input.txt` you may want to use `grep -F` if there are characters that are intended to be matched verbatim. Eg `.`

Comment: The above grep command is still not removing the records from Datatodelete.txt. It is still printing the whole content in dummy file

Answer (score 2):

An `awk` version:

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR{a[$1];next} !($1 in a)' InputData.txt Datatodelete.txt
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Flup, it does provide the output the OP seeks.

Comment: ...but doesn't answer the OP's question.

Comment: @Flup This isn't a story-telling competition.

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't want *`while read`* in there anywhere - *`sed`* will read your file. Next, you need to make sure that you handle *`greedy`* matches - *`sed`* will pull in as much as it can. So

```
    echo 1234 | sed -n '/123/p' 
1234
```

See? It prints it.

So you need, based on what you've shown, something like this:

```
    </home/InputData.txt \
        sed -n '/1234/s//& hellofirstline/p;\
        /123[^4]/s//& hellosecondline/p;\
        /14676/s//& hellothirdline/p;\ 
        /1453/s//& hellofourthline/p' >/home/dummy
```

If your *`sed`* script is in a file:

```
    </home/InputData.txt \
        sed -nf ./delete.sed >/home/dummy
```